# Importing site collection giving ReportServer Feature version error

Tags: 2013

I am using SP2013 and try to export a site collection from one server to another. Export is successful but while import it gives me the following error:

> Import-SPWeb : Feature 'ReportServer' is deployed but its version
>   '14.0.0.0' is below the minimum required version of '15.0.0.0'.

I have checked Report Server Version number on both servers and they are same. Any one have any idea or clue that what is happening behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rule of thumb is when you perform the export and import operation in sharepoint, Make sure that both source and destination sites/farm should be on same version level as well as same features installed on both.

If their is any mismatch then it will throws the error.

In your case culprit is the ReortServer feature which is looks like 2010 version, you need to upgrade that.